# if the limit of $(a_n)^2$ is infinite how can I prove that for $a_n$?

Tags: calculus

Hi I know that the limit of $(a_n)^2$ goes to infinite I feel like its pretty obvious that it means that the limit of $a_n$ goes to infinite as well but I couldn't find a good way to prove it.

Any thoughts? :)
Thanks in advance

EDIT: it is known that $a_n > 0$ (for almost all n)

Comment: Does $(a_n)^2$ mean $(a_n^2)$?

Comment: @choco_addicted hmm yes I thought it looks clearer that way (does it change the answer?)

Comment: Use the formal definition of the limit of $a^2_n$ being infinity to formulate the same for just the $a_n$.

Comment: @EHH was hoping to avoid the formal definition (always looks a bit weird to me) and maybe use some algebra for that with some rules

Comment: It is not at all obvious I think.. Take $a_n=(-1)^nn$

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake you are right I have edited the question to be more clear

Comment: @TheOne Thanks for your comment. I just wanted to avoid confusion from notation.

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake that sequence doesn't have a limit, but I guess you were just showing something close to a contradiction. The One, you need to get your head around the formal definitions of limits and convergence etc, it is the whole essence of this subject area. If you need help speak to a lecturer or someone but you need to uderstand this stuff. I can understand it seems weird at first but when it clicks it makes so much sense.

Comment: It just follows from the fact that $\lim_{x \to +\infty}  \sqrt x=+\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof by contradiction:

Let $a_n>0$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n\ne \infty$. That means, $\exists A$ such that $\exists N\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that for infinitely many $n\ge N$, $a_n\le A\implies a_n^2\le A^2$ for infinitely many $n$, which contradicts the fact that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n^2=\infty$

Answer (score 1):

We know that 
$$(\forall K>0)(\exists N \in \Bbb{N}, N=N(K))(\forall n\ge N)\\(a_n)^2>K$$
Since $a_n, K>0$ and $f(x)=\sqrt x$ is strictly increasing, it follows that
$$a_n>\sqrt K$$
So we have that 
$$(\forall \sqrt K=M>0)(\exists N \in \Bbb{N}, N=N(K))(\forall n\ge N)\\a_n>M=\sqrt K$$
as desired